# How can I debug an Android device without cable(Not even without the initial connection)

Tags: android, adb, android-debug, android-debugging

Typical way is

1. Connect PC to the device with USB Cable.
2. `adb tcpip 5555`
3. `adb connect 192.168.xxx.xxx:5555`

However, what if [the device manufacturer doesn't recommend this way](https://docs.sunmi.com/en/general-function-modules/second-screen-and-customer-display/t1-vice-screen/debugging-instructions/debugging-instructions/). But connect them directly wirelessly?

What they say is

1. PC and Device must use the same Wifi
2. Check IP address of the device.
3. `adb connect 192.168.xxx.xxx:5555`

[image]
And I found [this blog](https://medium.com/@reidzeibel/the-true-adb-via-wi-fi-no-cables-whatsoever-1e6c115956ff) that says I don't need to connect USB to the real device. But run anything adb to detect any one device.

1. Run an emulator.
2. `adb tcpip 5555`
3. `adb connect 192.168.xxx.xxx:5555`

However, I get `Connection refused` error with the second and third method. What should I do? How can I debug this device?

*The port 5555 is not being used.